# How to change PublicPath for Create React App in Dev Environment

Tags: reactjs, iis, development-environment, create-react-app, asp-net-core-spa-services

I am using [Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates::2.0.0-rc1-final](https://github.com/aspnet/templating) which internally uses [Create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/) and [AspnetCore.ReactDevelopmentServer](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions/ReactDevelopmentServer)

My Dev. Environment is using IIS for hosting multiple api's say api1 as http://localhost/api1 and api2 as http://localhost/api2

**Problem** is if I host my React app from [Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates::2.0.0-rc1-final](https://github.com/aspnet/templating) template to http://localhost/myApp - it expects the files are always served with PublicPath "/" and hence does not work.

I know [Create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/)'s Prod setup uses [PublicPath](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/next/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.prod.js#L27) from [PUBLIC_URL](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/next/packages/react-scripts/config/paths.js#L22) or [Homepage](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/next/packages/react-scripts/config/paths.js#L36) from package.json.

Is it possible to modify create-react-app setup to use a custom publicpath in Dev. environment?

Comment: I dont want to do eject and also not use CORS

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Using "proxy" in package.json will allow create react app to talk to server side in dev environment. I am using VSCode to run the app and because of proxy value - my app is talking to my IIS hosted services.

See this: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development

Answer (score 7):

You can set `PUBLIC_URL` in `.env.local` on your local machine.

Be careful to not have this file/variable set when building for release. You can read more about `.env` files on cra documenatation.

Comment: I thought only variables that started with REACT_APP_... was allowed in .env-files, PUBLIC_URL ends upp as "" (empty string) if I put it there

Comment: I was wrong about variables having to start with REACT_APP, from create-react-app.dev: Apart from a few built-in variables (NODE_ENV and PUBLIC_URL), variable names must start with REACT_APP_ to work. But I'm still getting empty string though..

Answer (score 5):

After doing some more googling and searching old issues on github, I have realized that this feature is due for release in react-scripts 2.0 which should include
 https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/1887. This will allow subpaths to be included in url from where the files are being served in create-react-app

Comment: Seems like it got moved to the 2.1.x milestone and has been in limbo for the past month: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/6280

Answer (score 3):

In your `package.json` add a `homepage` key. This will force all the files to be build with the prefix there defined.

```
// package.json
{
   "name": "my-project",
   "homepage": "/my-path",
   // ....
}
```

output:

```
/my-path/assets/my-asset.png
```

Answer (score 2):

After I enject the project, I saw these lines:

```
// We use `PUBLIC_URL` environment variable or "homepage" field to infer
// "public path" at which the app is served.
```

So, please update PUBLIC_URL in the environment file

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods depends on your needs

1. add **PUBLIC_URL** in .env.development file

   ```
   PUBLIC_URL=http://localhost:3000
   ```
2. add **homepage** attribute in package.json

   ```json
   // package.json
   {
      "name": "my-project",
      "homepage": "/my-path",
      // ....
   }
   ```

[Reference from source](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/20edab4894b301f6b90dad0f90a2f82c52a7ac66/packages/react-scripts/config/paths.js#L26)